# Is there a way to require PKCE for ALB Authetnication?

Tags: amazon-alb, oidc

We're using Okta OIDC to authenticate users to AWS ALB. I've got the basic version working.

**Is there a way to get it to require Authorization Code with PKCE to improve security?**

- [ALB Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html#oidc-requirements)
- [PKCE Docs](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-grant-type/authcodepkce/main/)